# Custom template for custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have problem with template for custom post type in Wordpress. I have tried many ways to do that but none of them worked... My post type is **post_product** and my slug is **produkty**. I have created single-post_product.php (and many other variations) but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
function post_product() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Produkty',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'archive' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'produkty'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-carrot',        
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'trackbacks',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author')
        );
    register_post_type( 'post_product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'post_product' );
```

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create file named single-produkty.php

Then go to Settings -> Permalinks and click Save. It should work now.

Comment: I write comment that it works but it really doesn't... I use function that show what template file are using and it still using single.php...

Comment: Try once again with single-post_product.php and refresh permalinks like I said in my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks man! That works. It is weird because I have tried this many times and it worked first time.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating `single-produkty.php` in your theme instead as the template requires the slug name in the template as that is what is used for the rewrite rules. Add the template and then go to ***`Settings > Permalinks`*** and save that page and that'll flush the rewrite rules just in case anything in cached.